# Как можно реализовать такой Scroll bar

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Здравствуйте, есть div практически на всю высоту страницы.Можно ли как то скролл страницы,который у body привязать в этому div?
Просто данные подгружаются,а у div сделано

```
overflow-y: scroll;
```

И я не хочу чтобы у этого блока был отдельный скролл.
Может как то позицию этому блоку задать.
Примерно как тут http://siliconrus.com/2015/05/marketing-courses/ реклама на месте,а центр прокручивается.
Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если я вас правильно понял, то сделать это не сложно.

Вам необходимо задать большую высоту body, затем повесить обработчик событий на скролл body и пробрасывать эти события в скролл div-элемента.

Для расчета высоты body смотрите в сторону пропорциональности отношений окно/контейнер div и body. А именно формула рассчета такова:

```
bodyHeight = windowHeight * divInnerContainerHeight / divHeight;
```